# PHP Session lost half way through buying process

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

**THE SET UP**

I have a buying process that has the following stages:

- results
- customer
- payment
- order-conf

The results page sets a session variable with an ID from our orders database table. Each page posts data to the next one. The start of **customer** and **payment** BOTH check the existence of the ID number session variable.

As you can imagine, 99% of browsers with default cookie settings have no problem with the setting of these sessions vars and reading them.

I get an alert whenever that session var check comes back as blank. Most of these errors seem to be direct hits to the customer and payment page, so BOTS or bookmark hits which all makes sense.

Sometimes we get alerts back from the **customer** page, with the referring URL as **results** saying the session was blank and it looks like a customer who has cookies disabled. Again, this is fair enough and up to the user to accept cookies.

**THE PROBLEM**

We are getting a handful of alerts per week from customers who have an empty order ID session var, but on the **payment** page (with the referring URL as **customer**). So they successfully pass the customer stage with the order ID var in existence. But when I recheck it on the payment page after they submit their personal info - **GONE**!

It makes no sense to me. How can it be fine on the previous page, but not on the next? The domain stays the same, all URLS are on HTTPS so it's not that.

My email includes PHP to loop through all SEssion Vars - and that is always blank. (So it's not just the single session variable that is blank, the whole lots is blank).

Is there any more debug I can add to these email alerts to see if the session is in tact, or rather it isn't? Here's some code:

customer and payment both start with:

```
<?php
require_once "../includes/common.php";

$quoteShared        = new quoteShared();

// Check if this is a direct page hit
if (requestSession("sessionid") == "") {

    echo $quoteShared->directHit();
    die;
```

Common includes the obvious at the start:

```
session_start();
```

How we check sessions:

```
function requestSession($xParam) {
    $value = "";

    if (isset($_SESSION[$xParam]))
    {
        if ($_SESSION[$xParam] != "") {
            $value = $_SESSION[$xParam];
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: users with their browsers in "porn mode" shutting that window and continuing on from another unrelated window?

Comment: Did you verify that there is absolutly no output before the end of your PHP code? Cookies cant be stored after any output. Common errors include spaces or invisible characters before `<?php`. And best to just leave `?>` out of all PHP files.

Comment: Marc B - I have tested our system in "icognito" / "porn" mode and can complete bookings no problem. ToBe - the issue you suggest would affect all orders wouldn't it, not just a handful per week? I set all cookies/sessions right away, then I start to construct the HTML to output.

Comment: @MarcB I have re-tested by getting to the half way stage of the order, having a surf around icognito, and then getting to the next stage of our booking process without error.

Comment: but if the entire surfing session was started icognito, then that cookie would ONLY exist incognito and be lost when that window's closed.

Comment: @MarcB arh I answered that just before you posted it. I've tested this out in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `requestSession` is missing $ just in your example code?

Comment: @ErsanJSano - nope, I've added that function into my question - it's self written and just the way we do it.

Comment: @MarcB - Could this be something to do with long visits timing out? My host has just said this is set in php.ini session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440. I have tried to change it to 60 on my WAMP install but I still can't replicate the problem.