# Are some users PHP Sessions expiring/timing out?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I'm relatively new to using PHP sessions on my website but we are experiencing a problem with some users losing their session mid buying process.

I suspect that some users are spending a long time in our buying process whilst they compare us to our competitors, and then when they try to move through our booking process the session has gone.

My web host said these settings are in our php.ini file:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_probability = 0
```

Do they look like normal settings? From that I would expect users who spend over 24 minutes on on page my booking process to lose the session if they move onto the next page.

I tried to duplicate these settings on my WAMP install, but set the maxlifetime to 60. I was hoping if I sat on a page for over 60 seconds I would lose the session on the next stage. But I just cannot duplicate the problem. Is it something to do with the divisor and probability settings that mean SOME users will experience the problems, SOME of the time?

Can someone suggest how I should set this up please?

More details about my buying process set up can be found here:

[PHP Session lost half way through buying process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407339/php-session-lost-half-way-through-buying-process)

Comment: With these settings your sessions will never expire.

Comment: How does that 1440 come into play then? We are definitely getting some users who have a session variable in in page then it does no exist on the next. Without any php affecting that specific one...

Comment: It's the time after which session is a candidate for GC. In your case GC is never invoked though (because `0 / 1000 = 0`)

Comment: Are there any other settings that I should check to see if they are the root of my problem? I'm really struggling to suss out what to do next on this :(

Comment: I think my problem could be a lack of a session_name("") - I have WordPress as well and that is also setting a PHPSESSID - does this sound like they could conflict?

Comment: @zerkms - 100% our server is clearing out sessions after 30 - 60 minutes with the above settings in place. I can now duplicate the problem by sitting on my results page for 30-60 mins and the next page will fall over due to there being no session variables. How on earth can I find out what is causing this if the above settings are correct?

Comment: the settings you provided do what I stated. You probably run something else there that is configured differently.